# Perl RegEx trouble with one or more of any char

Tags: regex, perl

This is my regex:

```
^.+\/.+\.sql.+$
```

it matches

```
/somedir/abc.sql.20121212
```

but it doesn't match

```
/somedir/abc.sql20121212 
/somedir/abc.sql_20121212
```

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't `sql.+$` mean match 'sql' and at least one of any character after it?

**UPDATE**:  The above regex does indeed work.  I was getting unexpected results because I hadn't saved the config file in which the regex is stored (DUH !!)  The previous value was `^.+\/.+\.sql\..+$` which means has to be  'sql.' and at least one of any character after it.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: Please post actual runnable code for an easily reproducible test-case.

Comment: your regex seems to be working

Comment: Yes, they *should* all match. My remaining hunch is a not-quite-saved file.

Comment: Since (as ikegami says in his/her answer) it *does* match them, the problem is probably in the surrounding code. If you'll post that code, you might get a useful answer . . .

Comment: **UPDATE**:  The above regex does indeed work.  I was getting unexpected results because I hadn't saved the config file in which the regex is stored (DUH !!)  The previous value was `^.+\/.+\.sql\..+$` which means has to be  'sql.' and at least one of any character after it.  Sorry for the false alarm.

Comment: -1 Sorry but I don't see why a post should be rewarded for not checking something as basic as this. Expresso or an online regex validator would have shown straightaway that all 3 strings match.

Comment: @DeanOC: perhaps the reward is for coming and telling us what the problem actually was :)

Comment: @ysth: As they say on the billboards, "Yeah right."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they do match:

```
print "$_: ", /^.+\/.+\.sql.+$/ ? 'match' : 'no match', "\n"
   for qw(
      /somedir/abc.sql.20121212
      /somedir/abc.sql20121212 
      /somedir/abc.sql_20121212
   );
```

Output

```
/somedir/abc.sql.20121212: match
/somedir/abc.sql20121212: match
/somedir/abc.sql_20121212: match
```